# Access AWS API Gateway with IAM roles from Python

Tags: python, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway that I would like to secure using [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) .

I am looking for a package to help me accessing it using Python. I am trying to avoid implementing the entire [Version 4 Signing Process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). I am sure there must be some library I can use.

I looked into [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth)  but it requires a "aws_service" to generate the signature. I looked also to boto3 but I am not able to find any way to just add authentication headers to a general request.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) to generate the signature for your request to API Gateway with **execute-api** as the service name.

```
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key='YOURKEY',
                       aws_secret_access_key='YOURSECRET',
                       aws_host='restapiid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                       aws_region='us-east-1',
                       aws_service='execute-api')

headers = {'params': 'ABC'}
response = requests.get('https://restapiid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource_path',
                        auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank, works like a charm. After setting Custom Domain Names I replaced aws_host and get URL with my own domain name.

Comment: Where do you normally go to find out that `execute-api` is the correct service name?

Comment: @TravisBear, looks like this link will help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonapigateway.html. Each service in the navigation on the left, when selected will show a 'service prefix' which is what you would use for this.

Answer (score 4):

Just to build on *Ka Hou Ieong*'s response, there is one other thing which tripped me up. I was using `aws-requests-auth==0.3.0`, and in using `requests.get(url, auth=auth)` I was still getting a `403`.

**;TLDR;**: My *URL* had a *querystring* and it looks like `aws-requests-auth` doesn't or probably cannot make sure the  *querystring* parameters are **sorted in ascending order** and `%`-encoded.

**==>** So once I changed my `url` querystring to be ordered and `%`-encoded, I got `200`.

**Details**:
I turned on API Gateway logging and I was getting

```
In [46]: resp = requests.get(url, auth=auth)

In [47]: resp.text
Out[47]: u'{"message":"The request signature we calculated
 does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key
 and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details....
```

*(the new lines and truncation(`...`) above is mine)*

Per the *Amazon [Canonical Request for Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)* documentation,

> To construct the canonical query string, complete the following steps:
>
> Sort the parameter names by character code point in ascending order. For example, a parameter name that begins with the uppercase letter F precedes a parameter name that begins with a lowercase letter b.
>
> URI-encode each parameter name and value according to the following rules:
>
> **a.** Do not URI-encode any of the unreserved characters that RFC 3986 defines: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen ( - ), underscore ( _ ), period ( . ), and tilde ( ~ ).
>
> **b.** Percent-encode all other characters with %XY, where X and Y are hexadecimal characters (0-9 and uppercase A-F). For example, the space character must be encoded as %20 (not using '+', as some encoding schemes do) and extended UTF-8 characters must be in the form %XY%ZA%BC.

That *canonical* querystring is used in generating the `Authorization Signature`, and AWS applies the same rules when calculating the `Signature Version 4` sig.
Bottom line, I think of course `aws-requests-auth` `Auth` of course cannot change your `url`, you have to.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make a call using the IAM role, you should use `BotoAWSRequestsAuth` from [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth):

```
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.boto_utils import BotoAWSRequestsAuth
auth = BotoAWSRequestsAuth(
    aws_host="API_ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    aws_region="us-east-1",
    aws_service="execute-api"
)
response = requests.get("https://API_ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/STAGE/RESOURCE", auth=auth)
```

This will use botocore to retrieve a key and secret from the AWS metadata service rather than you needing to pass them yourself.

Thanks to [Ka Hou Leong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357370/2800876) for the suggestion of the aws-requests-auth library.

Comment: Currently, it works, very convenient. If you don;t have the botocore module, execute pip install boto3 --upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

One more decision is using [requests_aws4auth](https://pypi.org/project/requests-aws4auth/) package:

```python
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = AWS4Auth(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 'us-east-1', 'execute-api')

response = requests.get('https://restapiid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource_path', auth=auth)
```

Also, you need to add execution permissions for your IAM user, like these (all API endpoints in the region can be invoked):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

More permissions examples can be found by [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html)